# How to Concatenate two variable in algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I need to add a statement (contains three words that come from 3 variables) to a file
for example:

```
Algorithm1
Input X,Y,Z: input words
Output: file:text file
Begin 
...\\some operations
...\\some operations
...\\some operations
file<-- X + Y + Z
End
```

I need a concatenation symbol other than +, which is used for mathematical operations, to concatenate X, Y, and Z and addd them as one statement in a file.

Comment: Many programming languages overload the `+`  operator to mean addition for numbers or concatenation for strings. If you want to pick a different operator, that’s entirely up to you. Recommendations from us would be a matter of opinion and are thus off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: I need something professional to be used in an algorithm in the dissertation. that's why I am asking here.

Comment: You said: "I need something professional to be used in an algorithm in the dissertation." What does that even mean? What's unprofessional about using an already widely accepted operator overload? Besides, it's pseudo-code. You can use any convention or nomenclature you like as long as you define it and use it consistently.